# How to get time of how long an object is grabbed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vrtk

Currently I am working on a project using Unity and the Virtual Reality Toolkit (VRTK). I want to log the times of the grabbed objects (How long the user grabs an object).

So far I got this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using VRTK;

public class System_2_Script_Slider_X : MonoBehaviour
{
    float Timer;

    void Start()

    {
        Timer = 0;

        if (GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Team3_Interactable_Object_Extension is required to be attached to an Object that has the VRTK_InteractableObject script attached to it");

            return;
        }

        GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>().InteractableObjectGrabbed += new InteractableObjectEventHandler(ObjectGrabbed);

        GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>().InteractableObjectUngrabbed += new InteractableObjectEventHandler(ObjectUngrabbed);
    }

    private void ObjectGrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)

    {
        //Some Code

        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    private void ObjectUngrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)

    {
        //Some Code

        File.AppendAllText("PATH/Timer.txt", Timer.ToString());

        Timer = 0;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as I get times of around 2 milliseconds even though I grabbed the object way longer. So it seems the `ObjectGrabbed()` function starts the timer but stops it immediately.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object grabbed function is likely only called once (when you grab).
It doesn't start a timer, it just add the time since last frame to your variable. If it is only called once, it will only add the time of one frame to the `Time` variable.

What you should do instead is register **when** the object was grabbed so you can compute the total length when it is released:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using VRTK;

public class System_2_Script_Slider_X : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _timeWhenGrabbed;

    void Start()
    {
        if (GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>() == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Team3_Interactable_Object_Extension is required to be attached to an Object that has the VRTK_InteractableObject script attached to it");

            return;
        }

        GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>().InteractableObjectGrabbed += new InteractableObjectEventHandler(ObjectGrabbed);

        GetComponent<VRTK_InteractableObject>().InteractableObjectUngrabbed += new InteractableObjectEventHandler(ObjectUngrabbed);
    }

    private void ObjectGrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)

    {
        //Some Code

        _timeWhenGrabbed = Time.time;
    }

    private void ObjectUngrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)

    {
        //Some Code
        var grabDuration = Time.time - _timeWhenGrabbed;
        File.AppendAllText("PATH/Timer.txt", grabDuration.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 seconds before I was gonna post my answer, you're a quick one Basile! Very good answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `ObjectGrabbed` method gets fired only when the `Grab` action occurs, and not every frame the object is grabbed.
So you should probably setup your code by using some `Timer` or `StopWatch` (The stopwatch has more precision).
By starting the timer into the `ObjectGrabbed` method and stopping the timer into the `ObjectUngrabbed` method.
Something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch;
...
private StopWatch Watcher = new StopWatch();
...
private void ObjectGrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)
{
    Watcher.Start();
}

private void ObjectUngrabbed(object sender, InteractableObjectEventArgs e)
{
    Watcher.Stop();
    long millis = Watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Watcher.Reset();
    File.AppendAllText("PATH/Timer.txt", millis.ToString());
}
```